# Custom TypeScript type from React imported library not recognized?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am attempting to use a third party family tree library (`react-family-tree`) in my React TypeScript project.

The family tree wants an array with among other values, a value in the Gender type from its dependency library `relatives-tree`

I have imported the library like so:

```
import ReactFamilyTree from 'react-family-tree';
```

And am attempting to create the Gender type in the array with the below code:

```
var ancestorsFormatted: Array<{ id: number, gender: Gender, parents: {id: number}[], children: {id: number}[], spouse: {id: number}[]}> = [];
```

However, I am given the error of `Cannot find name 'Gender'`

I thought that importing this library would also make its types usable, do I also need to import the dependency library? I tried doing so with a variety of syntaxes but it is not recognized.

Comment: "I thought that importing this library would also make its types usable" no, you have to import types explicitly just like values.

Answer (score 2):

`import ReactFamilyTree from 'react-family-tree'` only imports the default export from `react-family-tree`, which is not the `Gender`. You'll need to import `Gender` itself from somewhere.

If that's in the library `relatives-tree`, then this will likely be something like

`import { Gender } from 'relatives-tree'`.

You'll need to check the documentation/source though to understand exactly where you can find the `Gender` type.

---

Update: in this specific case, the `Gender` type seems to be exported from `relatives-tree/lib/types`, so the import statement should be:

```
import { Gender } from 'relatives-tree/lib/types'
```

Comment: I used your import statement you recommended but React complained that relatives-tree doesn't have an exported member named Gender. I looked through its source code and found a file named types.ts with an entry ```export const enum Gender {
  male = 'male',
  female = 'female',
}``` -- any idea how to adjust my import statement for it?

Comment: I had a look at the library, and it seems you'll need to have `import { Gender } from 'relatives-tree/lib/types'`. I found this by installing the package in my project, and then in `node_modules/relatives-tree` I found the `lib` folder with the compiled `types` file.